# Javascript function using var from another function

Tags: javascript, html

I came across a sample HTML/Javascript code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id='showCD'></div><br>
<input type="button" onclick="previous()" value="<<">
<input type="button" onclick="next()" value=">>">

<script>
var i = 0;
displayCD(i);

function displayCD(i) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            myFunction(this, i);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "cd_catalog.xml", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml, i) {
    var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; 
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
    document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML =
    "Artist: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Title: " +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "<br>Year: " + 
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

function next() {
if (i < x.length-1) {      // why does x here not raise an error? it came from nowhere.
  i++;
  displayCD(i);
  }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The only question I had is why is it okay to use `x` in `function next(){}` when it is defined in `myFunction(xml, i){}` ?

When the page first loads, displayCD(0) is executed. So the only theory I could come up with is `x` stays in memory because it is a global variable (it does not use `var`.)

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks

Comment: x without var becomes a global var when it is first used (here: `x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");`) - but where is next() used?

Comment: Where is `next()` even called? It's defined but not used so that may be why it doesn't give an error.

Comment: I don't fully grasp this concept. x comes from var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML; so xmlDoc is a local variable. when displayCD(0) finished executing, wouldn't xmlDoc (and XmlHttpRequest object) get destroyed? How then does x remain? Not sure how all this works.

Comment: @Bert, Hi, I missed a line when copy-pasting. I edited the code. The original link is http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_app_navigate

Comment: `x` doesn't "remember" how it got its value. Simplified example: if `a` is local, `b` is global and `var a = 1; b = a;` then the value of `b` will always be 1 (unless specifically changed) even if `a` doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @JJJ thanks. The word "remember" makes it all clear.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: `xmlDoc` is not linked to the value of `x` at all. The value assigned to `x` is the return value of the `getElementsByTagName`, which is a reference to an object created to the memory.

Answer (score 1):

When the function "myFunction" executes then, the variables without var is attached to window object. In console, you can see it by trying window.x and it will show some output.

Then, you can access x from any function or outside the function.

If you try to access x before executing "myFunction", then it will display error.

Comment: Beat me for a minute :( here a quick explanation about scopes which I think would make everything clear http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

You're wondering why encapsulation isn't occuring?  Because functions aren't treated as objects.  Variables in functions are always created on their parents scope.  But you can create encapsulated scope using javascript objects:

```
var a = {};
a.z = "a";
console.log(z);  //undefined error
```

Or you can wrap your functions like this to encapsulate them:

```
(function(){
  var x = "1";
})();
console.log(x); //undefined
```

Or better yet, create a scope:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject.myMethod = function(){
  var g = "2";
}
console.log(g); //undefined
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1a3tkzpz/1/